# $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ . . . prove that $f$ is bounded near $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Here's the problem: suppose $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ and that $|f(z)|<C/|z-z_0|^{1/2}$ near $z_0$ for some constant $C$. Prove that $z_0$ is a removable singularity, and in fact $f$ is bounded near $z_0$.

So we have some $R$ such that $|f(z)|<C/|z-z_0|^{1/2}$ when $0<|z-z_0|<R$, and I know all I need to show is that $f$ is bounded in this disk because this will immediately imply $z_0$ is a removable singularity. But I'm totally stuck on how to even begin showing this is bounded.

It seems to me $|z-z_0|^{1/2}$ could become as small as we want as we approach $z_0$, so $C/|z-z_0|^{1/2}$ would then become arbitrarily large. But I guess my thought process must be wrong somewhere. Does anybody see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function $(z-z_0)f(z).$

Comment: So, if I let $g(z)=(z-z_0)f(z)$, then in the region $0<|z-z_0|<R$ we have $|g(z)|<C|z-z_0|^{1/2}<CR^{1/2}$, so $g(z)$ is bounded. However, how does this help me see that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: It shows that $g$ has a removable singularity. So $g(z) = a_0 + a_1(z-z_0) + \cdots$ But we also know $g(z) \to 0,$ so $a_0 = 0.$

Comment: Yep, just realized that. Thanks!!